# React routing using old urls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react app. I want to redirect using my old url in react after signup or login. suppose user hit **http://localhost:3000/dashboard** then signup page will be opened like **http://localhost:3000/signup** but here dashboard is lost.. I want to save old  url like **http://localhost:3000/signup.required?dashboard** .and after logging or signing in **http://localhost:3000/dashboard** will be opened.

Comment: So create a redirect? What's the issue? I see no code here.

Comment: How to create redirect. can you provide same documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) or create HOC and use [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)